# Is there an adjective to describe systems of equations which is neither underdetermined nor overdetermined?

Tags: terminology, systems-of-equations

What might I call a system of equations in which the number of equations equals the number of free variables? In other words, if a system of equations is neither *underdetermined* nor *overdetermined*, then what is it?

Comment: Maybe: ''determined''  can work?

Comment: Critically determined would be my choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard terminology for this specific situation, although "critical" or "critically determined" as others have suggested can be appropriate.  But the comment thread on the question should be a good indication that it's best to avoid using a term like this (i.e., applying a word like "critical" in a context where it sort of makes sense but still isn't standard) without previously defining it.  I say this because two different people proposed two different, albeit very similar, answers within two minutes of each other.

I think the best course of action would be to define the term the first time you use it.  For example, if you're writing a scholarly article then you can say, "...for this **critically determined** system, i.e., neither underdetermined nor overdetermined..." or something to that effect.

Answer (score 0):

A system of equations in which the number of equations equals the number of free variables is often referred to as the **critical** case. It is the case between overdetermined and underdetermined, where for each variable giving a degree of freedom, there is a corresponding constraint removing a degree of freedom.